# Android: how to implement a 'game paused' screen with buttons

Tags: android, layout, overlay

I'm trying to create a 'game paused' screen that overlays on top of my game. The game itself runs in a GameView (extending SurfaceView). I would like the paused screen to have a layout with a number of ImageViews for buttons or animations, but I don't know how to put that layout on the screen without getting rid of the GameView behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a relative layout and hide/unhide could be possible.

Comment: Although, I am unsure how to reference my pausedLayout from within my GameView. I have a world class within GameView that takes care of pausing and unpausing the game, and somehow I need to set the visibility from there.

Comment: Add and remove it programatically or inflating it from an xml file (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this

Instead of opening a new axtivity stop the current drawing loop and draw your pause screen and add button and images in by drawing itself.

Answer (score 0):

See my another answer how programmatically show an overlay layout on top of the current activity. Activity's layout.xml does not need to know anything about the overlay skin. You can put overlay semi-transparent, cover only part of the screen, one or more textview and buttons on it...
[How to overlay a button programmically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983632/how-to-overlay-a-button-programmically/14248874#14248874)

- create res/layout/paused.xml RelativeLayout template or use any layout toplevel
- create a function to show overlay skin
- key is to get handle to layout.xml, use LayoutInflater class to parse xml to view object, add overlay view to current layout structure
- My example uses a timer to destroy overlay object by completely removing it from the view structure. This is probably what you want as well to get rid of it without a trace.