# How to create an info overlay in Android

Tags: android, overlay, showcaseview

I am looking for a way to create a short overlay intro of an app to display to first time users. These posts gave me some understanding of how it can be done, but not entirely:

[How do I create a help overlay like you see in a few Android apps and ICS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216937/how-do-i-create-a-help-overlay-like-you-see-in-a-few-android-apps-and-ics)

[How to use LayoutInflater / ViewStub for an overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285022/how-to-use-layoutinflater-viewstub-for-an-overlay)

I do not understand how to access my elements correctly, since my root layout element is a `LinearLayout` that includes an `Actionbar` and a `ViewPager` instead of containing actual elements.

Are there any frameworks that does this for you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that this library : [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) is your best option.
As its name implies, it allows you to recreate the Android 4.x showcase view; ie :
[image: Showcase view sample].

The documentation of the project explains how to implement it.
Word of advice though : this kind of explanation view is viewed as bad design most of the time : if your application is well designed, you don't need to provide a tutorial to the user, it is supposed to be intuitive.
It can be totally justified in some cases of course, just be sure that :
-your users really need a tutorial.
-it is not because you are doing something opposite to the Android convetions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MaterialShowcaseView](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView). It inherits from [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) and is up-to-date.

[image: Example image]